# how to serialize vector clocks so that thy can be sorted by lexicographical order

Tags: database, computer-science, distributed-computing

Is there a way to serialize a vector clock so that, when comparing 2 vector clocks, I can just compare the string?

When using LevelDB, I want to be able to store the vector clock as part of the record key, and take advantage of the sorting of the database keys that LevelDB does for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this, because strings compare equal if and only if the entire contents is the same, and a vector clock can compare neither greater than or less than a non identical clock.  For example, the clocks `[2,1]` and `[1,2]` would be have to compare "equal". To satisfy that condition when serialized to a string, they would have to map to the same string.  If they map to the same string, you would not be able to deserialize them to different clocks.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit late to the party, but I had the same issue at work, and found a solution.  You have to relax the constraints of the problem a bit, but then it should work enough for creating a valid global ordering in a distributed system.

In proper vector clocks A and B,

- A > B **iff** (if and ONLY if) all elements in A are >= element in B
- A and B are concurrent if not (A > B or B > A)

Thus we have three states - before (<), after (>) and concurrent.  With string, we only have two valid comparison values, < and >. Given these constraints, we can relax the constraints a bit and get the following:

- str(A) > str(B) **if** (no only here) all elements in A are >= element in B
- if A and B are concurrent, both str(A) > str(B) and str(B) > str(A) are acceptable

With these constraints, if we order all events by their serialized string value, we get a *possible* global ordering, which is consistent with all partial orderings provided by the vector clocks.  That means all events are positioned after all their causes and before their effects. The only trick is we need a unique integer identifier for each actor, but we need something like that for vector clocks anyway.

I made a python library to do just this, please take a look: https://github.com/ethanfrey/vclock

If you just want to look at how I serialize the vector clocks, take a look here.  ArrayCodec relies on the vclock stored as an array, indexed by the actor's id. DictCodec relies on a dictionary with key being the integer actor's id.  The base implementation supports 256 actors and 16 million events on one clock, with 6 bytes per actor, but that can easily be scaled up by using more bytes for the serialization:

https://github.com/ethanfrey/vclock/blob/master/vclock/codec.py